# Using nodes to navigate a maze

Tags: graph, nodes

The following figure is called a graph. The circles are called nodes and the lines are called edges. An edge connects two nodes. You can interpret the graph as a maze of rooms and passages. The nodes canbe thought of as rooms and an edge connects one room to another. Note that each node has at most four edges in the graph below (N,S,E,W).

Write a program that implements the maze above using references to instances of a Node class. Each circle in the graph will correspond to an instance of Node. The edges correspond to links that connect one node to another and can be represented in Node as instance variables that reference another Node class. Start the user in node A. The user’s goal is to reach the finish in node L.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzifh.jpg)

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node() { north = south = east = west = NULL; visited = false; }
    Node(char newID) { north = south = east = west = NULL; visited = false; ID = newID; }
    char getID() { return ID; }
    void setConnections(Node *n, Node *s, Node *e, Node *w)
    {
        north = n; south = s; west = w; east = e;
    }
    Node* getNorth() { return north; }
    Node* getSouth() { return south; }
    Node* getEast()  { return east; }
    Node* getWest()  { return west; }
    void setVisited()
    {
        visited = true;
    }
    // Only needed for AUTO-SOLVE
    bool getVisited() { return visited; }
    // Only needed for AUTO-SOLVE
private:
    char ID;
    bool visited;
    // Only needed for AUTO-SOLVE
    Node *north, *south, *east, *west;
};

int main()
{
    Node *A = new Node('A');
    Node *B = new Node('B');
    Node *C = new Node('C');
    Node *D = new Node('D');
    Node *E = new Node('E');
    Node *F = new Node('F');
    Node *G = new Node('G');
    Node *H = new Node('H');
    Node *I = new Node('I');
    Node *J = new Node('J');
    Node *K = new Node('K');
    Node *L = new Node('L');

    A->setConnections(NULL, E, B, NULL);
    B->setConnections(NULL, F, NULL, A);
    C->setConnections(NULL, G, D, NULL);
    D->setConnections(NULL, NULL, NULL, C);
    E->setConnections(A, I, NULL, NULL);
    F->setConnections(B, NULL, G, NULL);
    G->setConnections(C, K, H, F);
    H->setConnections(NULL, L, NULL, G);
    I->setConnections(E, NULL, J, NULL);
    J->setConnections(NULL, NULL, NULL, I);
    K->setConnections(G, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    L->setConnections(H, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    Node*current = A;
    cout << "You are in room " << current->getID() << " of a maze of twisty little passages, all like. You can go: " << endl;
    if (current->getNorth())
        cout << "north (n) | ";
    if (current->getSouth())
        cout << "south (s) | ";
    if (current->getEast())
        cout << "east (e) | ";
    if (current->getWest())
        cout << "west (w) | ";

    string go;
    cin >> go;

    if (go == "n")
        current = current->getNorth();
    else if (go == "s")
        current = current->getSouth();
    else if (go == "e")
        current = current->getEast();
    else
        current = current->getWest();
    while (current->getID() != 'L')
    {
        cout << "You are in room " << current->getID() << " of a maze of twisty little passages, all like. You can go: " << endl;
        if (current->getNorth()){
            cout << "north (n) | ";
            current = current->getNorth();
        }
        if (current->getSouth()){
            cout << "south (s) | ";
            current = current->getSouth();
        }
        if (current->getEast()){
            cout << "east (e) | ";
            current = current->getEast();
        }
        if (current->getWest()){
            cout << "west (w) | ";
            current = current->getWest();
        }
        cin >> go;
    }
    if (current->getID() == 'L')
        cout << "Congratulations! You made it.";

    return 0;
}
```

I just do not know what's wrong because it seems like my while function is not working. Here is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPxHd.jpg)

Thank you